# DDD Large Aggregates

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I have an `Appointment` Aggregate Root, for the aggregate to be valid in terms of the business it must have a reference to a number of other aggregates which increase the size dramatically; `Client`, `Employee`, `Service`, Start/End Date and Time.

The `Appointment` is rehydrated from a web service and it seems it would be impractical to fetch all of this information every time I want to get a list of appointments or even just a single appointment.

I must be doing it wrong, the `Client`, `Employee`, and `Service` are themselves aggregate roots with their own repository like interface, as they can all exist by themselves.

Would it be an idea to just keep the `IIdentity` of the aggregates in the `Appointment` aggregate root and load them separately when needed (eg. `ClientId`, `EmployeeId`, `ServiceId`)?

I find this to be a very common problem with my first foray into DDD.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: You should read 'Effective Aggregate Design' by Vaughn Vernon.

Comment: Funny you should mention that I've already downloaded the PDF's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rule of aggregates is that anything that belongs to the aggregate cannot be accessed from outside the aggregate root. By having a `Client`, `Employee` and `Service` part of your aggregate, you are breaking this rule.

It's better to just have an Id to those entities and break up your aggregates so that they don't interfere with eachother.

Comment: That's a good rule, so any time my aggregate roots need a reference to another aggregate root it should be their identity only?

Comment: In general yes, although you should try to minimize dependencies between aggregate roots.

Comment: I try to build my aggregates with the least amount of information as possible that still fits the business model.  In this case I have the absolute minimum as far as I can see (with the aggregate roots replaced with identities). Thank you :)